# Double sided faces with transparent texture are black on one side

Tags: three.js, textures, transparency

In ThreeJS I have some plant objects that are just double sided faces with a texture on them. The texture has transparent pixels. I have alphaTest set to 0.5. One side of the face is showing the texture and transparent pixels are really transparent. At the other side, the transparent pixels are black - and not transparent.

I have tried turning depthTest off. That does remove the black, but it introduces a lot of new and even worse problems. But it might be a clue that it has something to do with depth.
I also tried a custom depth Shader with alphaTest set to 0.5, but that does not appear do anything.
It also is not a lighting issue, I have tried to light the dark side with several types of lights, but no results there.

Comment: Let's see your code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3):

It was a side effect of the OutlineEffect. When I turned that off, the plants were transparent on both sides. Luckily you can switch it on or off for every material, so I do not need to remove it entirely.